# How can I set a radiobutton to checked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

Here's my code, running is JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/ZbFWu/31/

I'd like that radiobutton to select itself when I click anywhere inside the `.paymentoption` div tag.

Any suggestons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to attach your events when the DOM's fully loaded by wrapping your functions in `$(document).ready()`, and there's a slight error in your code.

```
$(this).$('input[name="paymenttype"]').prop('checked', true);
```

won't work, you need to replace it with:

```
$(this).find('input[name="paymenttype"]').prop('checked', true);
```

It's fixed at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbFWu/35/).

Answer (score 4):

What about this HTML/CSS only option? Much cleaner, and works without Javascript. And it actually gives your radiobutton a label, making it better accessible by screen readers for the visually impared as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/ZbFWu/37/

Comment: Can I give that label a background image like I can a div? Does it work well across browsers?

Comment: A label is an element like any other. It is an inline element by itself, but if you add `display: block`, it behaves like a div in every aspect I can think of. It is more or less a span with a built in click handler, as long as you specify the linked control in the 'for' attribute. It should work well across browsers, although I don't have an old IE6 at hand to test it.

Comment: Meh, **screw IE6**. Thanks, this will work nicely and without bloat.

Comment: Tested it on my virtial machine (with IETester). Works in IE6. IE5.5 won't render jsfiddle at all. :D But apart from that, I know it works, and it's recommended to use labels for controls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ?

```
$('.paymentoption').click(function() {
    $('.paymentoption input[name="paymenttype"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbFWu/34/